# Document ContainerElement metadata / id

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to read/write metadata to a Document ContainerElement in apps script? I feel like there must be a way. Even to be able to fetch a ContainerElement id will work since I can store metadata matching that id in a separate datastore. I don't see anything in the documentation, not even how to get an id.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/container-element

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you are trying to accomplish? I think the closest you will be able to do is mixing Named Ranges and Document Properties

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing. It's still not perfect but it seems to be working for now. I was just looking for a mechanism to retrieve a previously found element. I'll have to work on it a bit more to see if I run into any limitations with namedRange.